# when can i draw solid life time at sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I saw on a video that sometimes life line in sequence diagram can be solid   but the author doesn't explain more this point.

I searched more in the net but i don't find more response.

Comment: Maybe if you explain **why** you thought it was desirable after seeing the video it would be easier to understand what you are looking for?

Comment: See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html

Answer (score 2):

According to section 17.3.4.1 of 2.5 UML specification:

> A Lifeline is shown using a symbol that consists of a rectangle
>   forming its “head” followed by a vertical line (**which may be dashed**)
>   that represents the lifetime of the participant.

As you can see it's up to you if you use solid or dashed lifeline. However indeed dashed line is more popular.

The only thing I would recommend is being consistent across a single model (if you use dashed line use it for all lifelines in a particular model, and **definitely** for particular diagram).